# How to move ApiModelProperty list value outside "[" in Java

Tags: java, swagger

In the A_Bean class, it has List<B_Bean>, and I use @ApiModelProperty to set the value as the list description.
But it is displayed on the web page, I want the description text to be displayed before the "[".
How can I achieve the desired effect?

I want to move the text with the red bottom line to the position pointed by the red arrow.:
[image: I want to move the text with the red bottom line to the position pointed by the red arrow.]

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: _"I want the description text to be displayed before the `[`"_ I think Swagger UI always displays array descriptions _inside_ [ ].